# how to get the text from the HTML using java code?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

In this HTML code , i need to get the "**Status**" text using selenium testng.

```
          <div class="dojoxGridSortNode">Status</div>
```

i used the code as

```
    public static String gettext(){
   String Value = null;
try{
    Value = webElement.getAttribute("text");
    APP_LOGS.debug("Get Text on"+locatorDescription);
   }
```

using this code,i cant get the text from the html code.Is their any other option to get the text from the html attribute? i used .getText() method also.

Thanks in advance

Comment: how to use in jsoup?

Comment: like this http://jsoup.org/cookbook/

Comment: **getText()** method must work. If you don't pass the correct webelement, then it won't. Please try to use the correct Webelement in order to get the text.

Comment: What exactly is your `webElement`? Please make sure to read the answer in the above linked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the WebElement as a parameter to properly use your method.

The webelement can be this (**As per the HTML snippet, you've added**):

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='dojoxGridSortNode']"));
```

And, your method can be modified to this:

```
  public static String gettext(WebElement webElement){
   String Value = null;
try{ 
    Value = webElement.getText();
    APP_LOGS.debug("Got Text: "+Value); 
    return Value;
   }catch(Throwable e){
     //Catch body
    } 
 }
```

**You can pass the concerned WebElement as a parameter to the method above and call the method to get the required text**

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Naveen's comment, you can try-

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(<YOUR URL>).get();
Elements elements= doc.select("div[class=dojoxGridSortNode]");
String str = elements.text();
```

You can download Jsoup jars from here - http://jsoup.org/download